# Similar to currency-abstraction, could there be cryptography-abstraction (free market for digital signatures on a single state)?

Tags: evm, signature, cryptography

Currency-abstraction for mining rewards was planned for Serenity, and so on, and so is out there as an idea. I thought about "signature-abstraction", so that different digital signatures could compete within a single state. Would that make sense in the context of Ethereum or Ethereum 2.0?

Comment: Somehow related is account abstraction https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18977/what-is-the-ethereum-account-abstraction. An account will have code to verify transactions, and will be able to use a different type of signature.