# Why contract accounts can only be activated by an Externally Owned Account (EOA)?

Tags: eoa

Why contract accounts can only be activated by an Externally Owned Account (EOA)? And not vice versa? Contract Accounts activating EOA?

What is the design principle behind this?

Answer (score 1):

EOA's are controlled by public/private key pairs, while contracts are controlled by smart contract logic defined in it's code. Currently I believe there is also a distinction in that an EOA is presumably a human, and contract accounts are well, contracts.

This system however is only temporary, as the ultimate goal is to make the two indistinguishable through account abstraction.

[What is the ethereum account abstraction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18977/what-is-the-ethereum-account-abstraction/19456)

Comment: what is the purpose to make both indistinguishable?

Comment: See the link I posted, it goes into details about why that is the end goal