# Using ECC Brainpool curves instead of Elliptic Curves

Tags: cryptography

I am exploring the use of ECC Brainpool curves instead of elliptic curves for digital signatures in Ethereum.

Is this part of the roadmap and/or anyone has experimented with the use of ECC Brainpool Curves?

Comment: There's a proposal for account abstraction so you can use your own signature mechanism https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-86.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the ethereum account abstraction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18977/what-is-the-ethereum-account-abstraction)