# Is there a plan / EIP for native multi-signature transactions?

Tags: transactions, eip, wallet-contracts

We have a 2-of-3 multi-signature wallet contract which works fine. However, when sending to exchanges or wallets which use RPC calls (rather than contract events) to capture incoming transactions, they do not see ours (see [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/how-to-get-contract-internal-transactions) for why).

It seems reasonable and useful to have native multi-signature addresses which can *initiate* transactions and be treated as first-class senders in transaction objects.

Does anyone know of a plan to add this feature in an upcoming protocol update, or an EIP on which to discuss it?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, there's no plan for it. When we met Vitalik in Hanoi, we also asking about the multisig and threshold signature then he answered that there's no clear reason to support it native so if you have clear reason to request it you can make your own EIP though.

Answer (score 0):

[Account Abstraction](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18977/what-is-the-ethereum-account-abstraction/19456), should enable this, assuming it gets finalized and included. You can see in the Account Abstraction EIP, [Vitalik said](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/859#issue-292549143):

> It will be possible for accounts to use whatever signature scheme they
>   want